# Load data in partial view from database in Laravel 5.8 and include that view in Master Layout

Tags: laravel

I am creating a blog using Laravel 5.8. I have a created master layout containing navbar, sidebar and footer. Rest areas are yielded in the subsequent layouts. Since I have included sidebar in the master layout file, my query is how can i load categories in the sidebar from the database.

The current situation is: I have kept the categories static.

Main Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Aarthna Maheshwari" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="A fully functional blog made from scratch using HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Boostrap and Laravel In India" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/css/blog.css') }}" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Laravel Blog - A complete blog with admin panel created using HTML and Laravel with Bootstrap</title>

<style>
    .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
            font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
  <header class="blog-header py-3">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <div class="col-4 pt-1">
        <a class="text-muted" href="#">Subscribe</a>
        <a href="/create" class="nav-item">Create</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <a class="blog-header-logo text-dark" href="#">Large</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
        <a class="text-muted" href="#">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" class="mx-3" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" focusable="false"><title>Search</title><circle cx="10.5" cy="10.5" r="7.5"/><path d="M21 21l-5.2-5.2"/></svg>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Sign up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>



<div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">
    <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">

      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">World</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">India</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Technology</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Design</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Culture</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Business</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Politics</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Opinion</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Science</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Health</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Style</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Travel</a>
    </nav>
  </div>



<div class="jumbotron p-4 p-md-5 text-white rounded bg-dark">
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
      <h1 class="display-4 font-italic">Title of a longer featured blog post</h1>
      <p class="lead my-3">Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.</p>
      <p class="lead mb-0"><a href="#" class="text-white font-weight-bold">Continue reading...</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">Featured post</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 12</div>
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
        <div class="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
          <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-success">Design</strong>
          <h3 class="mb-0">Post title</h3>
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 11</div>
          <p class="mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="stretched-link">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="200" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 blog-main">
      @yield('content')
    </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

    <aside class="col-md-4 blog-sidebar">
      <div class="p-4 mb-3 bg-light rounded">
        <h4 class="font-italic">About</h4>
        <p class="mb-0">Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="p-4">
        <h4 class="font-italic">Archives</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled mb-0">
          <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">February 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">January 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">December 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">November 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">June 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">May 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">April 2013</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>

      <div class="p-4">
        <h4 class="font-italic">Elsewhere</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </aside><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

  </div><!-- /.row -->

</main>

   <footer class="blog-footer">
      <p>Blog template built using <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a> by <a href="Aarthna Maheshwari">Aarthna Maheshwari</a>.</p>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Back to top</a>
      </p>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Expected output:
The app should load the categories from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use view composer for to load your category each time your sidebar template are loaded.
see here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers